# OSMDroid map repeating

Tags: android, osmdroid, repeat

I'm making an Android App using OSMDroid library, i load my .mbtiles map from the assets folder.

The problem is that it's displaying an infinite number of maps not only one.

I tried to fix it with map.setScrollableAreaLimit(map.getBoundingBoxE6()); but it is deprecated and doesn't work, is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't need this anymore, but since I searched for this myself and there's no answer I thought I'd write what I've done:

```
MapView map;
map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(true);
map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
```

Notes:

- This cuts some of the map (top and bottom) and this is why:
  I've tried to use `map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(90, -90, 0);` and got an ANR. After some searching I found `TileSystem.MaxLatitude` which is depreciated, and found this [documentation](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/debug/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.html#setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude-double-double-int-). So it seems that you can either have a repeating full map or have it cut a bit.
- I did not try to play around with the top\bottom values to get a little extra.
- I've decided to have horizontal repeat because it seemed more natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

You already not osmdroid display many times the map, to solve it, you can stop this behavior with this below code.

```
 double DEFAULT_ZOOM = 3;
// Don't repeat map
    map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
    map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);

    //limit map don't go forward screen size
    map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
    map.setScrollableAreaLimitLongitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLongitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLongitude(), 0);

    map.getController().setZoom(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    map.setMinZoomLevel(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30334258)